# String split with minimum size

Tags: python

I am writing a python script that will accept a dot-delimited version number. It will split this string into individual components (using period (`.`) as a delimiter). My script supports up to 4 components (e.g. `1.2.3.4`). However, the user may specify *less* or *more* components than 4 and my script needs to be able to handle it.

If less than 4, the list that I get back from `string.split()` needs to be resized to 4 and missing components initialized to the string `"0"`. If greater than 4, just truncate the elements past the 4th component.

The truncation is easy, I would just splice the list. However, I'm not sure how to perform the resize up to 4 elements. Is there a pythonic way of doing this, or do I need to hand-write a bunch of logic to do it?

I'm using Python 3.2.

Comment: You could adapt e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24067079/3001761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generally check the length of the list and just add the missing list back to the start:

```
def pad_list(input_string, pad_length, pad_char='0'):
    base_version = input_string.split('.')[:pad_length]
    missing_entries = [pad_char] * pad_length - len(base_version)
    return base_version + missing_entries
```

Really the only addition here is to actually check the length of the partial list you're getting and then create another list with the same length as the missing section.

Alternately, you could just add the 0's ahead of time in case it's too short:

```
(a + '.' + '.'.join(['0'] * 4)).split('.')[:4]
```

The idea behind the second line here is to preemptively add zeros to your version string, which effectively eliminates your padding issue.

First, we add `'.' + '.'.join(['0']*4)` to the end of the string `a`, this adds `.0.0.0.0` to the end, which means that effectively the padding is there regardless of what's in the rest of the string.

After the padding is there, you slice as you normally would: `.split('.')[:4]`

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain the 2nd snippet piece by piece? Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @RobertDailey Done, let me know if anything's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick

```
def GetVersionList( version_string ):
    vlist = version_string.split('.')[:4]
    vlist.extend('0' * (4 - len(vlist) ) )
    return vlist
```

Or a more general version

```
def FixedLengthListFromString( input, length, delimiter='.', padChar='0' ):
    vlist = input.split(delimiter)[:length]
    vlist.extend(padChar * (length - len(vlist) ) )
    return vlist
```

Comment: Maybe people downvote because the solution doesn't look very "pythonic", but I don't care as long as it works. Not everything has to be done in one line of code!

Comment: Some of the downvotes may have been for the PascalCase and strange use of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> (['0'] * 4 + "4.5".split('.'))[-4:]
['0', '0', '4', '5']
>>> (['0'] * 4 + "4.5".split('.'))[-4:]
['0', '0', '4', '5']
>>> (['0'] * 4 + "2.4.5".split('.'))[-4:]
['0', '2', '4', '5']
>>> (['0'] * 4 + "1.2.4.5".split('.'))[-4:]
['1', '2', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Good answer, but I should have specified the padding should go on the right side, not the left :-)

Comment: ("1.2".split('.') + ['0'] * 4)[:4]

Answer (score -1):

If your list is `a` and you want to pad it out to 4 elements

```
 a = a + [0]*(4-len(a))
```

Will do the padding you require.

This works because with any list `l`, `l * x` will create a new list with the element of `l` repeated `x` times so `[0]*4` is just the list `[0,0,0,0]`. And `len(a)` is the current length of your list so `4-len(a)` is the number of extra elements required.

Comment: Yes, I did, and it does.

Comment: >>> s = '1.2.3.4.5'
>>> s = s + ['0'] * (4-len(s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: @JackAidley Once again, `a` is definitely NOT a string.

Comment: Here: https://ideone.com/smCWdA - OP is asking how to pad out their SPLIT string to the correct number of elements. They've already worked how to limit it to four elements so it's just a matter of padding out.

Comment: @JackAidley yes, but if you explicitly say something different, then it's still incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide an example value for `a`?