# Get a minimum number of elements from split()

Tags: python, string, split

Imagine a string containing (comma) separated elements, e.g. a version string

```
version_str = "3,1,4,159"
```

which *might* contain one or more elements more or less:

```
version_str = "3,1,4"
```

or

```
version_str = "3,1,4,159,appendix"
```

And I want to separate these elements like this:

```
major, minor, patch, revision, appendix = version_str.split(',')
```

Then of course I get an `ValueError` because the number of extracted elements does not always match.

Is there a way to `extend` the result of `split()`, e.g. like this:

```
version_str.split(',', min_elements=5)
```

or

```
version_str.split(',').extend(5, default='')
```

?

Example:

```
>>> '3,1,4'.split(',', min_elements=5)
['3', '1', '4', '', '']

>>> '3,1,4,159,dev'.split(',', min_elements=5)
['3', '1', '4', '159', 'dev']
```

Of course I can add elements manually afterwards or read elements conditionally, but I'm interested in the pythonic one-liner.

Comment: I dont get it. the split does it well and make sure its in a try/catch section so that it restricts the number of elements. Maybe im not understanding the issue

Comment: `zip([major, minor, patch, revision, appendix], version_str.split(','))`

Comment: or `major, minor, patch, revision, appendix = version_str.split(',')[:5]`

Comment: Related: [String split with minimum size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24092149/3357935)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `zip_longest` in one line:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
major, minor, patch, revision, appendix = [x + y for x, y in zip_longest(
                                           version_str.split(','),  [''] * 5, fillvalue='')]
```

or:

```
split = version_str.split(',')
major, minor, patch, revision, appendix = split + [''] * (5 - len(split))
```

Comment: I like your answer because it's a real one-liner and it shows that there seems to be no intuitive way to do this yet.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such functionality out-of-the-box but you can write your own function that does the trick for you:

```
def split_with_min(str, min_r, delimiter=',', default='NA'):
    temp = str.split(delimiter)
    return temp + [default] * (min_r - len(temp))


print(split_with_min('1,2', 5, ',', 'NA'))          # -> ['1', '2', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
print(split_with_min('1,2,3,4,5,6', 5, ',', 'NA'))  # -> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

---

Now for the *one-liner* requirement, you could condense the above if you do not mind calling `split()` twice:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = my_str.split(',') + ['NA'] * (6 - len(my_str.split(',')))
print(f)  # -> 'NA'                              ^ number of variables we are defining
```

Answer (score 1):

```
version_str = "3,1,4,159,appendix"

version_str_1 = "3,1,4"

version_str_2 = "3,1,4,159"    

from collections import namedtuple

version = namedtuple("version", "major minor patch revision appendix")

version.__new__.__defaults__ = (None,) * len(version._fields)

print(version(*version_str_2.split(',')))
>>>version(major='3', minor='1', patch='4', revision='159', appendix=None)

print(version(*version_str_1.split(',')))
>>>version(major='3', minor='1', patch='4', revision=None, appendix=None)

print(version(*version_str.split(',')))
>>>version(major='3', minor='1', patch='4', revision='159', appendix='appendix')
```

to access individual fields:

```
get_version = version(*version_str_2.split(','))
get_version.major # '3'
get_version.minor # '1'
get_version.patch # '4'
get_version.revision # '159'
get_version.appendix # None
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a small inline(Or a normal) function that parse the version string

```
>>> version_parser = lambda s: "{},{},{},{},{}".format(*s.split(',') + ([""] * (5-len(s.split(',')))))
```

Then invoke it like

```
>>> version_parser('3,1,4,159').split(',')
>>> ['3', '1', '4', '159', '']

>>> version_parser("3,1,4").split(',')
>>> ['3', '1', '4', '', '']

>>> version_parser("3,1,4,159,appendix").split(',')
>>> ['3', '1', '4', '159', 'appendix']
```